# My Android drawing application is crashing somewhere in native code

Tags: android

my Android vector-drawing application is uncommonly crashing somewhere in native code. I cannot catch the crash with Java try-catch block, I can see it only in the Google Play Developer console in the "Crashes and ANR's" section.
Here is the trace from the console:

```
   Build fingerprint: 'samsung/kltexx/klte:5.0/LRX21T/G900FXXU1BOJ1:user/release-keys'
   Revision: '14'
   ABI: 'arm'
   pid: 31153, tid: 31153, name: ...  >>> ... <<<
   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x65eb3cf4
   r0 65eb3cf4  r1 a75f2764  r2 7fffffff  r3 be8c15ec
   r4 af56a838  r5 7fffffff  r6 be8c1570  r7 b4efac6c
   r8 b4efac6c  r9 be8c15c0  sl 00000000  fp be8c1590
   ip b4efac6c  sp be8c1528  lr a75f2760  pc b5a60ae6  cpsr a0000030

   backtrace:
   #00 pc 000ecae6  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkRegion::Oper(SkRegion const&, SkRegion const&, SkRegion::Op, SkRegion*)+861)
   #01 pc 000ecc67  /system/lib/libskia.so (SkRegion::op(SkRegion const&, SkIRect const&, SkRegion::Op)+28)
   #02 pc 000969df  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
   #03 pc 00ba8897  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Can anyone help me? How can I locate the problematic place in my code?
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to use MintExpress https://mint.splunk.com/ or similar sdk to track crashes ??

Comment: I'm using the Google Analytics + Google Developer console, which gives me the error trace log. But my question is about the concrete error - does anybody know what is a reason of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the crash was my own fault:
I'm using the [android.graphics.Region](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html) class in my application. I'm calling the Region.op() method and a problem was that I was calling the method from two different threads.
These operations aren't thread-safe, so that was the reason of the crashes.